# Django, avoid N+1 query

Tags: django, django-models

I have three models in play, and want to avoid N+1 query.

```
class Rule(models.Model):

    pass


class RuleConstraint(models.Model):

    rules = models.ManyToManyField(Rule)


class Foo(models.Model):

    rule = models.ForeignKey(Rule, related_name='foos')
```

for a given foo, I can get related RuleConstraints like the following

```
RuleContraint.objects.filter(rules__foos=foo)
```

Question is, how do I avoid N+1 query symptom, when I have `foos` instead of a single foo.

ie, is there a better way of doing than

```
for foo in foos:
  rule_constraints = RuleConstraint.objects.filter(rules__foos=foo)
```

Comment: Did you look at the `select_related` method? https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/models/querysets/#select-related

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want `prefetch_related`

```
foos = Foo.objects.prefetch_related('rule__rule_constraint')
```

You can then iterate through the queryset with:

```
for foo in foos:
    rule_constraints = foo.rule.ruleconstraint_set.all()
```

You can improve this further by using `select_related` to fetch the `rule`.

```
foos = Foo.objects.select_related('rule').prefetch_related('rule__rule_constraint')
```

For more information see [the prefetch related docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/models/querysets/#prefetch-related) - your models are very similar to those in the examples.